# What is eating up my CPU?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, mysql, php, cpu

I am facing a difficult situation.
100% CPU but I cannot see a singular process using much in top or htop.

I run this command:

```
:~$ ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k 1 -r | head -10
%CPU   PID USER     COMMAND
 5.1    34 root     [kswapd0]
 2.4     1 root     /sbin/init
 2.3  1815 mysql    /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 0.6 25583 super    top
 0.5 12964 mysite /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2
 0.4 13313 mysite /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2
 0.4 13311 mysite /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2
 0.4 13310 mysite /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2
 0.4 13309 mysite /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2
```

This does not explain why top & htop show 100% CPU.

```
top - 22:17:15 up  3:14,  2 users,  load average: 104.14, 102.73, 87.49
Tasks: 392 total, 103 running, 251 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 25.7 us, 72.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.6 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  2040972 total,    77924 free,  1666072 used,   296976 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  3906244 total,  1093324 free,  2812920 used.   187268 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   34 root      20   0       0      0      0 S 17.7  0.0  11:06.77 kswapd0
 1815 mysql     20   0 1395428  24804    600 S  7.2  1.2   4:11.76 mysqld
    1 root      20   0  225472   4396   2768 S  4.6  0.2   4:50.26 systemd
31359 root      20   0  189660  68472   2124 R  2.0  3.4   0:02.34 /usr/share/webm
12975 mysite  20   0  522728  16780   2500 R  1.0  0.8   0:08.91 php-cgi7.2
13278 mysite  20   0  522728  17000   5372 R  1.0  0.8   0:08.27 php-cgi7.2
13311 mysite  20   0  522728  16468   3092 R  1.0  0.8   0:08.07 php-cgi7.2
28715 super     20   0   32716   2112   1108 S  1.0  0.1   0:04.79 htop
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  0.7  0.0   0:23.60 ksoftirqd/0
12964 mysite  20   0  522728  17032   2504 R  0.7  0.8   0:09.36 php-cgi7.2
13008 mysite  20   0  522728  15728   2752 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.70 php-cgi7.2
13031 mysite  20   0  522728  18820   5808 R  0.7  0.9   0:08.72 php-cgi7.2
13039 mysite  20   0  522728  15856   2412 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.75 php-cgi7.2
13053 www-data  20   0  199312   6332   4336 R  0.7  0.3   0:00.46 apache2
13085 mysite  20   0  522728  16700   2440 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.60 php-cgi7.2
13094 www-data  20   0  199312   6896   4608 R  0.7  0.3   0:00.49 apache2
13125 mysite  20   0  522728  11152   2764 R  0.7  0.5   0:08.54 php-cgi7.2
13134 mysite  20   0  522728  19504   2780 R  0.7  1.0   0:08.58 php-cgi7.2
13161 mysite  20   0  522728  15324   2728 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.55 php-cgi7.2
13164 mysite  20   0  522728  15444   2480 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.54 php-cgi7.2
13174 mysite  20   0  522728  11712   2816 R  0.7  0.6   0:08.65 php-cgi7.2
13178 mysite  20   0  522728  12808   2768 R  0.7  0.6   0:08.57 php-cgi7.2
13185 mysite  20   0  522728  16080   2388 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.51 php-cgi7.2
13208 mysite  20   0  522728  13268   2424 R  0.7  0.7   0:08.38 php-cgi7.2
13210 mysite  20   0  522728  12744   2824 R  0.7  0.6   0:08.42 php-cgi7.2
13229 mysite  20   0  522728  15552   2704 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.46 php-cgi7.2
13230 mysite  20   0  522728  14944   2484 R  0.7  0.7   0:08.43 php-cgi7.2
13235 mysite  20   0  522728  15592   2468 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.42 php-cgi7.2
13236 mysite  20   0  522728  13832   2724 R  0.7  0.7   0:08.34 php-cgi7.2
13267 mysite  20   0  522728  16212   2488 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.36 php-cgi7.2
13275 mysite  20   0  522728  16228   3036 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.28 php-cgi7.2
13280 mysite  20   0  522728  15872   3140 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.23 php-cgi7.2
13284 mysite  20   0  522728  17144   5536 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.14 php-cgi7.2
13287 mysite  20   0  522728  15416   6132 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.31 php-cgi7.2
13288 mysite  20   0  522728  16024   3088 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.17 php-cgi7.2
13289 mysite  20   0  522728  14048   6344 R  0.7  0.7   0:08.23 php-cgi7.2
13291 mysite  20   0  522728  16468   2828 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.09 php-cgi7.2
13294 mysite  20   0  522728  15120   6196 R  0.7  0.7   0:08.16 php-cgi7.2
13296 mysite  20   0  522728  11564   3236 R  0.7  0.6   0:08.10 php-cgi7.2
13300 mysite  20   0  522728  17032   3104 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.15 php-cgi7.2
13303 mysite  20   0  522728  15636   3108 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.19 php-cgi7.2
13306 mysite  20   0  522728  17340   5720 R  0.7  0.8   0:08.12 php-cgi7.2
```

I tried this:
I stopped mySQL and CPU dropped to 20%~30% range (mostly apache processes in htop).
I stopped apache and CPU dropped to 0%~2% range.
I started mySQL and CPU STAYED at 0%~2% range.
I started apache and CPU went to 100% immediately.

I can communicate with mySQL using workbench even when server is at 100% (albeit the fetch completes in 2 seconds instead of 0.08s).
However, Apache is completely useless and times out.
Thanks for helping.

**UPDATE #1**

I have 7 large processes >1%cpu (49.4% cpu total):

```
303 mysql   15.00%  /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
            
34  root    10.40%  [kswapd0]
12926   root    10.10%  [/usr/share/webm] <defunct>
13082   root    5.80%   /usr/share/webmin/authentic-theme/stats.cgi
10154   root    2.90%   /usr/share/webmin/virtual-server/collectinfo.pl
1   root    2.50%   /sbin/init
32750   super   1.10%   htop
```

I have 100 processes like (40% total cpu):

```
mysite 0.40%    /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2
```

I have 6 small processes <1%cpu (1.6% cpu total):

I have 152 small processes like <0.0%cpu (??% cpu total):

```
www-data    0.0%    /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I have 134 small processes <0.0%cpu (??% cpu total)

The 152 & 134 small processes must total around 9%, since the rest total 91%.

**UPDATE #2**
Why do I have 152 apache processes running?
This is my apache mpm_prefork.conf file. I guess I am hitting the MaxRequestWorkers limit?

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxRequestWorkers     150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Is my server under attack or is this normal? Any ideas how to go about this before I delete everything and install from scratch?

**UPDATE #3**

I think this is a DoS attack. I created a firewall in the VPS control panel (outside the VPS itself) and allowed incoming traffic only from my private IP. CPU is down to 0.7%. I do not think my clientele has increased 100-fold in a day! My VPS provider is looking into this as we speak. I will update.

Comment: Do you have any warnings/errors/information in the system logs? If not, a process could be asking for lots of memory. You are already using swap, swapping in/out takes time.

Comment: I checked mySQL, apache, syslog and cannot see anything amiss.
[suexec:notice] [pid ] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[so:warn] [pid] AH01574: module headers_module is already loaded, skipping
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1j configured – resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid] AH00094: Command line: ‘/usr/sbin/apache2’
[mpm_prefork:error] [pid] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

Comment: Given you have not given us a full ps listing, that `kswapd` is running high, and what you have given us is a large list of `php-cgi7.2` processes all running - `R`, then I would assume that is where the problem lies. You have 103 processes all currently in the run queue.

Comment: I have managed to get a full list of processes and analysed them. see update. I have to find out what the PHP processes are doing and why.

Comment: With 150 possible requestworkers and a database, 2Gb of memory is a bit miserly, no?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes... if they all get up and start working 24hours a day! Since the server went online it has been working at a stable 25% cpu, 30-90% RAM and some swap usage. It is fine for its purpose.

Comment: You'd still want to reduce maxrequestworkers to something your system can handle.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille you are right. at idle the system is using 560M RAM. 2000-560 =1440 / 16M = 90 maxrequestworkers. which will still fill up the RAM. What do you suggest?

Comment: I wouldn't calculate, but run one of the http tests and see when the machine starts swapping. Then back off a couple of workers. This will leave you room for intervention when the funny guys find another angle of DoS attack.

Comment: I'm somehow doubtful that a defunct process would take CPU at all... `12926   root    10.10%  [/usr/share/webm] <defunct>` I mean, it might have took 10% while it was running, but it's not taking anything after it finished.

Comment: @aviro look at the stats, it's not the (defunct) user processes that consume the CPU, but the system that's swapping.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, I see the line with the `kswapd0` above the defunct line that shows it's taking 10.40%, but there's another line bellow it that shows that defunct pid 12926 consumes 10.10% CPU.